# Fit text to a div. Django template

Tags: html, css, django, templates

I need to fit a text into a div inside in my template.

Now I have:

```
<td>
<div id="beruf" style="width:490px">
    {{profil.beruf|safe}}
</div>
</td>
```

But the text displays "to the end" without respect the width of the div.

Any ideas?

Thanks ;)

---- more info. This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: What does your context variable actually render?

Comment: you should add more information - possibly a js fiddle with all the relevant css and markup

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MAM7q/ Here, I see a good result ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some css is breaking the word-wrap?
Check this:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp